# Blocking I/O in Project Reactor pipeline

Tags: java, project-reactor

The following code uses Project Reactor to distribute a blocking I/O operation across a bounded number of worker threads:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

...

    List<Item> processItems(List<Item> items) {
        final int parallelDegree = 10;
        final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("myScheduler", parallelDegree, true);

        return Flux.fromIterable(items)
            .parallel(parallelDegree)
            .runOn(scheduler)
            .map(this::doSomeBlockingIo)
            .sequential()
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .collectList()
            .block();

    ...

    Item doSomeBlockingIo(Item item) {
        // perform some non-deterministic, blocking I/O with side-effects
        ...
        return someNewItem;
    }
```

The code appears to work fine as-is. But is it robust and idiomatic?

Note I've checked and see nothing in Project Reactor documentation (including JavaDocs) that clearly prohibits this use case.

Asking for a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine, it's robust, but the fact you're using a parallel scheduler for blocking IO work isn't optimal (and isn't particularly idiomatic; when someone experienced in reactor sees a parallel scheduler, they expect to see it running non-blocking IO.)

The better approach here would be to swap out your parallel scheduler for a [bounded elastic scheduler](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#newBoundedElastic-int-int-java.lang.String-) with a cap of your choosing (10 in your example) - this will spin up and reuse backing workers as necessary, up to your cap.